# How to identify text is selected using Jquery - Disallow Copying Content

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have website where i don't want to allow user to copy and paste content until they are member.

Below is requirement

1. Disallow Copying of Content within particular div tag to "Anonymous user" and display her message that "You will be allowed to Copy ones you become member of this site"
2. Ones user becomes member and trying to copy he/she should be allowed to copy the content.

I can disable Copy by adding following CSS

```
.ProtectCopy {
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
```

And i can add this CSS Tag to div content using Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=MyDivCnt.ClientID%>").find("div").attr("class", "ProtectCopy");       
    });
</script>
```

**My Question**

How can i identify whether user has select text from specific div tag?  I want to display message based on "Anonymous" or "Member" - "You will be allowed to Copy ones you become member of this site"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the [select](http://api.jquery.com/select/) event, which should help you do what you're asking.

Edit: That only works for `<input text="text">` and `<textarea>` elements. See [this article](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html) for detecting selection anywhere.

Also, I'm sure you're aware already but just like code that prevents users from right clicking, this can be easily circumvented by anyone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: If user do view source and copy that is not a problem, but i just want to avoid them to copy things directly

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem with this. If you put it out on the web... it is public domain. There is **NOTHING** you can do to prevent someone from getting that content.

- I could view source, and copy and paste from there.
- I could save the web page content to my hard drive and then it's mine forever.
- I could take a screenshot and hand transcribe the data.

Long story short. You will be wasting your time chasing this problem because it won't solve the issue.